# How to define image-resize?

Tags: scheme

I am trying to define a procedure **image-resize** that takes an image and a non-negative integer pixels, and returns a new image formed by carving pixels vertical seams from the given image. The original image is unchanged. I have no clue how to even write this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in c-211, you would have had to complete number 6 from the homework to do this problem (and make sure that your energy proc is right)

Comment: for the 6th problem what exactly would I be calling energy on? I have the lets already